# Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution

The probability that a certain radioactive mass emits no particles in a one-minute time period is 0.1353. What is the mean number of particles emitted per minute?

From the above I was able to deduce that P(X>=1) is 1 - 0.1353 = 0.8647.

0.8647 chance of at least 1 particle being emitted in a minute.

I'm not sure how to calculate the mean number of particles per minute though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you know?  You know that P(X = 0) = 0.1353.  correct?  What does the probability mass function of a Poisson distribution look like? $P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$  Since you can punch in P(X = 0) = .1353 for k = 0, you can back out the lambda value.  Now what is the mean of a Poisson distribution?  I'll leave that up to you....

Comment: Thank you very much. I came up with the same revelation right before you posted. I came up with lambda = 2.000261 as the mean. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: itsSLO - looks right to me

Comment: what does `k` represent in Poisson's formula?

Comment: in this case, k represents a certain number of arrivals or events occurring over a certain period of time.  Since the person wanted to know the $\lambda$ value, and knew the answer for k = 0, then it should be easy to back out the answer he/she needed.